# 4k video not supported by some common video file formats (mpeg2/avi)?

Tags: video-encoding, avi, mpeg

I've authored some 4k videos and to my surprise it seems that Adobe Media Encoder won't let me export using various common formats at 4k resolutions.

For example mpeg2 won't go above HD 1920 resolution if you manually try to change the video size parameters.   A little reading online seems to indicate this may be a technical limitation of the file format rather than anything specific with the AME software.  I won't post links here as this was just talk on forums.

I then tried the same thing with AVI's and had the same issue of not being allowed to enter a resolution this high.

Is it really the case that formats such as mpeg2 and avi have some basic limitation that means they can't support resolutions as high as 4k ?

I've been using mp4 so far as an output format but just wondered if I should be aware of other formats that have this technical limitation and are not going to work.

Comment: mpeg2 codec or container? avi is just a container, and uses a 32 bit number for demential resolution. It doesn't care. Also don't forget that even if the format is not limited, the implementation may be.

Comment: I believe mpeg2 container and codec.  Standard options within AME basically.    But can you confirm if any technical limitation would stop mpeg2 going above HD resolution?

Comment: mpeg2 part 2 I believe is limited to 1920x1080. But mpeg2 part 1 is not.

Answer (score 0):

The MPEG2 standard does not specify an encoding level for video at 4k resolution.

You can see a summary of what's available here:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H.262/MPEG-2_Part_2#Video_profiles_and_levels